# How to pull out a comma separated index list of all the missing files inside a directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I currently have a directory `/mydir`, and inside are supposed to be 1000 data files of the form `File1.exe, File2.exe, ... , File100.exe`.

I currently have a for loop that searches and outputs which files are missing:

```
for((i=1; i<=1000; i++))
do 
    name="File.${i}.exe"; [[ ! -e "$name" ]] && echo "$i" 
done
```

I am wondering if there is any way to instead of echoing the missing index, to put it into a comma-separated list instead, such as:

`1,5,20,40,etc`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *into a comma-separated list* - what do you mean, an array or a single string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use, for comma separated string, keep on adding your files index to a variable and print the variable

```
for((i=1; i<=30; i++))
do
    name="File${i}.exe"; [[ ! -e "$name" ]] && files="$files$i,"
done
echo $files | sed  s/,$//
```

Or you can store the values in an array/list

```
arr=()
for((i=1; i<=30; i++))
do
    name="File${i}.exe"; [[ ! -e "$name" ]] && arr+=($i)
done
(IFS=, ; echo "${arr[*]}") #to print the array with comma as separator
```

Comment: To print an array as a comma-separated string you can do `(IFS=,; echo "${arr[*]}")` -- I do that in a subshell so the effects of altering IFS are localized.

Comment: Thanks @glenn for the suggestion, that was really useful, I have included in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `/bin/sh` and the list of positional parameters to store the names of the missing files:

```
set --
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 1000 ]; do
    name="File.$i.exe"
    [[ ! -e "$name" ]] && set -- "$@" "$name"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

( IFS=','; printf 'Missing files: %s\n' "$*" )
```

or using `bash` and an array:

```
missing=()
for (( i=1; i<=1000; ++i )); do
    name="File.$i.exe"
    [[ ! -e "$name" ]] && missing+=( "$name" )
done

( IFS=','; printf 'Missing files: %s\n' "${missing[*]}" )
```

When using `"$*"` or `"${missing[*]}"`, the array will be converted to a string.  The string will be joined with the first character of `$IFS` as the delimiter (by default a space).  The subshell sets `IFS` to a comma, then prints the array joined on commas.  The subshell stops the variable `IFS` from being set in the rest of the script.

The code would also be able to deal with filenames containing spaces etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste` tool, just add `| paste -sd,` to the loop:

```
for((i=1; i<=1000; i++))
do 
    name="File.${i}.exe"; [[ ! -e "$name" ]] && echo "$i" 
done | paste -sd,
```

Explanation:

> **paste - merge lines of files**
>   paste [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>   With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

- `-s`: paste one file at a time instead of in parallel
- `-d`: delimiter (`,` in this case)